# How to run run.exe(Win+R) with parameters in delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

I want to open something by using run.exe(Win+R) and different commands , I wonder how to use Delphi code to do that?

for example how to use Delphi code to do this : `Win+R` -> input ：`control admintools` -> Run. it will open `Administrative Tools` folder；

Comment: There is no such thing as 'run.exe'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx).

```
uses
  Windows, ShellAPI;
....
ShellExecute(0, nil, 'control', 'admintools', nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: You are so fast. when only one parameter , is correct use like that : `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'control', '', nil, 0);` ?

Comment: I just find it can't open with this : `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'favorites', '', nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);` but run.exe can.

Comment: Not sure how Win+R resolves that one. You can get the folder location with `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` passing `CSIDL_FAVORITES`, and then open that folder.

Comment: It can open like this : `ShellExecute(0, nil, 'shell:Favorites', nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`  strange...

Comment: And I Find it isn't work `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}`  run.exe can popup the `connect to`  so strange...

Comment: Could  use like : `ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'Explorer.exe',
    'shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)`